# Linux Kernel's build configuration with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, linux-kernel

I try to use Eclipse to browse the Linux Kernel sources.

How can I make Eclipse aware of what is set as build configuration in `.config` respectively `#define`ed in `include/linux/autoconf.h`?

I'm using Eclipse's Juno Service Release 1 (Build id: 20120920-0800) on Debian (stable).

Useful would be something like `gcc`'s option `-include <file name>` on project base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this procedure to configure Eclipse to work with the Linux kernel.
http://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source

Comment: Steps 15 and 16 didn't make sense to me, until I upgraded to the latest Eclipse.