# Configuring Eclipse for Linux Kernel module development

Tags: linux, eclipse, kernel

I'm trying to configure Eclipse for developing Linux Kernel Modules under Ubuntu. So far I've added to `Properties` > `Paths and Symbols` > `Includes` > `GNU C` headers from directory `/usr/src/'uname -r'/include` but it doesn't remove all the `Syntax error` from my code.

After that, my code looks like this:

[image: code after headers added to path]

What else should I do to develop Kernel modules with pleasure?

Comment: Use `emacs` not *Eclipse* for kernel development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux Kernel's build configuration with Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897390/linux-kernels-build-configuration-with-eclipse)

Comment: @Federico this is not duplicate. I'm trying to configure Eclipse for Kernel Modules development, while you gave me Eclipse configuration for browsing kernel source code. That's not the same.

Comment: it is a different way to ask the same thing. Anyway, you cannot easily remove all the Eclipse warnings. The main solution to your problems is written in the other question

Comment: @Federico I'm almost sure you are wrong. In my opinion writing modules and browsing kernel source are two totally different things. Please show me why do you think that's the same.

Comment: @crooveck I'm wrong on many things. But if you want to remove most of the 'syntax warnings/errors'; eclipse must be able to _browse_ the whole kernel source and correctly _index_ it

Comment: ok @Federico you were right ;) 
I've done what you suggested and now everything works nicely and smoothly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're interested, those orange squigglies are actually indexer markers. Turn them off by going to window/preferences/general/editors/text editors/annotations, select c/c++indexer markers and uncheck 'text as'.

Also, this was posted on the Eclipse wiki: http://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source

Answer (score 1):

If you are building an Out-of-Tree kernel module, follow the steps in the CDT wiki (linked in @pjenney58's response).

The key difference is at Step 30 (**Source Location**->expand your project name).

1. Instead of adding a filter to your own source folder, choose "**Link Folder...**" to add the kernel source.
2. Check 'Link to folder in the file system' and select the path to your kernel source.
3. Click Ok, then follow the instructions for adding the filter (steps 31 & 32 in the wiki) but do it on the kernel source instead of your module folder.

In my project that took care of almost all the indexer markers complaining about syntax errors.