# Configure Eclipse for kernel module development

Tags: linux, eclipse, kernel, eclipse-cdt, kernel-module

I am trying to configure Eclipse for building a custom kernel module. For that, I am using my own custom makefile, which is not managed by Eclipse. I have got everything working (the code compiles), apart of the IDE "seeing" all of the sources and not yielding errors:

[image]

I tried following this guide: [Configuring Eclipse for Linux Kernel module development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168095/configuring-eclipse-for-linux-kernel-module-development) but it did not help me.